# How to pass variable in extended master template from blade template in Laravel5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel and facing problem to pass `{{$page_title}}` variable to master template which is extended in another blade template. My goal is to pass the `$page_title` to the master template where I want to show it in title in `<title>@yield('title', "Laravel CRUD")</title>`. Here is my code.

Controller

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index(Request $request){

        $data = array("pate_title"=>"Home");


        return view('home.index', $data);

    }//end function

}
```

This line is in my master template

```
<title>@yield('title', "Laravel CRUD")</title>
```

Home.index view template

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', {{$page_title}}) //error in this line

@section('content')

    <p>This is my body content.</p>
    {{$pate_title}}
@stop
```

Marked line in home.index view has a syntax error and it says `Expected: semicolon` and it doesn't work. I know it must be a very silly problem but didn't find anything after googling. Maybe I didn't put the right keyword in google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. Used following line

```
@section('title')
    {{$page_title}}
@stop
```

instead of

```
@section('title', {{$page_title}})
```

and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to omit the braces:
`@section('title', $page_title)`.